# oauth-1.0a Node package returning 401 for Zotero API (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, oauth

I'm using the oauth-1.0a Node package to implement OAuth with the Zotero API.

I'm using the code found in the [zotero-oauth-example repo](https://github.com/tnajdek/zotero-oauth-example).

Running the code in the repo mentioned above works. I think my implementation is not working because I've split up the single function in the repo into two functions --> the example repo doesn't handle redirecting the client and handling the callback.

**What I think the issue is:**
I think that instantiating two different OAuth objects (one is step 1, the other in step 3) is breaking something. Note that I'm temporarily persisting the hash produced in step 1's `hash_function` which is used in step 3.

I'm not familiar with OAuth. Do you have any suggestions on what I should try?

1) Request Token (server)

```js
// omitting includes packages
const tokenRequestConfig = {
        url: 'https://www.zotero.org/oauth/request',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
           

 oauth_callback: baseURL, // redirect to baseURL
            },
        },

        initZoteroIntegration = async () => {
            let oAuthHash;

            const oauth = OAuth({
                    consumer: {
                        key: process.env.ZOTERO_APP_CLIENT_KEY,
                        secret: process.env.ZOTERO_APP_CLIENT_SECRET,
                    },
                    signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
                    hash_function(base_string, key) {
                        oAuthHash = crypto.createHmac('sha1', key).update(base_string).digest('base64');
                        return oAuthHash;
                    },
                }),

                tokenRequestResponse = await fetch('https://www.zotero.org/oauth/request', {
                    headers: oauth.toHeader(oauth.authorize(tokenRequestConfig)),
                    method: 'post',
                }),

                tokenRequestData = await tokenRequestResponse.text(),
                obj = {};

            tokenRequestData.replace(/([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/g, (m, key, value) => {
                obj[decodeURIComponent(key)] = decodeURIComponent(value);
            });

            const oAuthToken = obj.oauth_token,
                oAuthTokenSecret = obj.oauth_token_secret,
                url = `https://www.zotero.org/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=${oAuthToken}&library_access=1&notes_access=1&write_access=1&all_groups=write`;

            /* the url should be returned to the client */
            return ({
                url,
                oAuthToken,
                oAuthTokenSecret,
                oAuthHash,
            });
        };
```

2) Client is directed to Zotero app to log in in and authorize permissions.

3) Token Exchange (server)

```js
// omitting includes packages
const confirmIntegration = async ({oAuthToken, oAuthTokenSecret, oAuthVerifier, oAuthHash}) => {
            const oauth = OAuth({
                    consumer: {
                        key: process.env.ZOTERO_APP_CLIENT_KEY,
                        secret: process.env.ZOTERO_APP_CLIENT_SECRET,
                    },
                    signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
                    hash_function() {
                        return oAuthHash;
                    },
                }),

                tokenExchangeConfig = {
                    url: `https://www.zotero.org/oauth/access?oauth_token=${oAuthToken}`,
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        oauth_verifier: oAuthVerifier,
                        oauth_callback: baseURL,
                    },
                },

                tokenExchangeResponse = await fetch(`https://www.zotero.org/oauth/access?oauth_token=${oAuthToken}`, {
                    headers: oauth.toHeader(oauth.authorize(tokenExchangeConfig, {
                        public: oAuthToken,
                        secret: oAuthTokenSecret,
                    })),
                    method: 'post',
                }),

                tokenExchangeData = await tokenExchangeResponse.text();

            try {
                const username = tokenExchangeData.match(/username=(\w+)/)[1],
                    userID = tokenExchangeData.match(/userID=([0-9]+)/)[1],
                    userAPIKey = tokenExchangeData.match(/oauth_token_secret=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/)[1];


            return {
                    username,
                    userID,
                    userAPIKey,
                };
            } catch (e) {
                // TODO throw some error
                return null;
            }
        };
```

On the 'Token Exchange' step I'm getting a response with a 401 status code ("Unauthorized").

`tokenExchangeResponse.text()` is returning `oauth_problem=signature_invalid`

Here's the raw output:

```
"https_sig_error=1&z_debug_sbs=POST&https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zotero.org%2Foauth%2Faccess&oauth_consumer_key%3D9a016199db19772cb220%26oauth_nonce%3DDs3iXBVWF4izl1qfX0mk0JXIvZkl7N5o%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1545238813%26oauth_token%3D6f6ade01f30625feeb36%26oauth_verifier%3D02469ed77305b02befd8%26oauth_version%3D1.0&oauth_problem=signature_invalid&debug_sbs=POST&https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zotero.org%2Foauth%2Faccess&oauth_consumer_key%3D9a016199db19772cb220%26oauth_nonce%3DDs3iXBVWF4izl1qfX0mk0JXIvZkl7N5o%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1545238813%26oauth_token%3D6f6ade01f30625feeb36%26oauth_verifier%3D02469ed77305b02befd8%26oauth_version%3D1.0"
```

***Fix**
Ok, I found a solution. I'm using `node-cache` to cache the OAuth object for a limited time.

Thank you @tnajdek for clarifying that the above usage of OAuth was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Note that I'm temporarily persisting the hash produced in step 1's
>   hash_function which is used in step 3.

This will not work.

The `hash_function` argument to `OAuth` constructor takes a `base_string` (which is a serialized summary of your request) and a `key` to produce its result. Both the `base_string` and the `key` will differ between steps 1 and 3, however your hash_function returns a cached results from step 1 as a result for completely different arguments `base_string` and `key` in step 3.

I'm not sure how the rest of your app looks like but I'd create `OAuth` instance just once and re-use it in the initial request and within the callback request inside your server request handling routines. If that's not an option, you can recreate `OAuth` using the same arguments and it should work fine.